# Key value in AWSIoTDataManager

Tags: swift, mqtt, aws-iot

I am working with a project where I don't get it the value of 
 awsiotdatamanager is static string or it generated from AWS. I found it like this in [sample code](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/IoT-Sample/Swift) Also I read code  [this](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSIoT/AWSIoTDataManager.h) and [this](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSIoT/AWSIoTDataManager.m) but I am getting more and more confused.

```
  let AWSIoTDataManager = "MyIotDataManager"
    let iotDataManager = AWSIoTDataManager(forKey: AWSIoTDataManager)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I've never worked with AWS IoT, but I've used other AWS libraries and the key has always been a user-defined string. It's used when you register your configuration and, as shown in your code above, to retrieve it. This allows you to have multiple `AWSIoTDataManager`s in your project.

Comment: @Don Thanks for reply. But this key should be register on AWS and then in my code. right ?

Comment: I don't believe you need to do anything on AWS. If you look at their sample code in ConnectionViewController.swift, they have this line: `AWSIoTDataManager.register(with: iotDataConfiguration!, forKey: ASWIoTDataManager)`. I'm pretty sure the key can be any String you want. You just need to use the same String when calling `let iotDataManager = AWSIoTDataManager(forKey: ASWIoTDataManager)`.

Comment: Okay, now I am clearly understood, Thank you  @Don